# PHP and custom HTTP headers, bad practice?

Tags: php, http, http-headers

I have a custom implementation of a RESTful API for a PHP application that returns json data, and in order to communicate the status of the operation, ie whether there were failures in the request, I'm setting a custom HTTP Header with a (very tiny) json object as a string. This works well since I can send responses and easily retrieve them client side without messing with the actual data sent.

The question is, are there any drawbacks I may not have realized of using this method? It doesn't seem to be very common for applications to set custom http headers, so I'm wondering whether it is a bad practice or bad "taste" somehow.

Comment: You mean in the status code? Like "200 {error:true}" ? Or a real header as "X-Something: whatever"?

Comment: The HTTP spec already addresses this. If there was a failure, you should return the proper HTTP status code and a description of the error in the body, not a custom header.

Comment: What if there is no proper HTTP code for the error in question?

Comment: @Artefact2 Then send a valid HTTP code that indicates a generic error (e.g. 500) and embed a specific error code in the returned JSON data.

Comment: @Artefact2: I've never came across an error that I couldn't find a HTTP code for. You mind giving an example?

Comment: @Savageman a real header such as "X-Something", yes, sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: @netcoder, these "errors" are not HTTP errors per se, but rather application errors while generating the returning json data; i.e. "the data was retrieved but watch out with abc property because I couldn't find its entry in xyz list". I understand what HTTP statuses are but imho, they would not fit here.

Comment: Also inserting them in the body would mean sending additional json properties, hence why I came up with the headers method (just trying to explain my reasoning here, perhaps it is still against the HTTP spec)

Comment: @Mahn: I understand you're basically saying you are accepting malformed requests instead of flagging them as errors. If `abc` doesn't exist, it should be a `400 Bad Request` response and the call shouldn't have any effect. If you want your API to be RESTful, you have to use HTTP status codes, period.

Comment: Not necessarily malformed, imagine you are asking for two icecreams and I return you one; it's not what you expected, but you can still do something with it (provided you handle it properly)

Comment: +1 for giving out icecreams. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is an interesting question. There shouldn't be any reason for it to be a problem, but you should take a few things into account:

1. The headers need to be unique to your application. Not just now, but forever. You should ensure you're prefixing them, e.g. `X-MyApplication-Foo: Bar`. Not doing this might cause conflicts in future.
2. Firewalls are *sometimes* (rarely) a little overzealous with filtering unknown HTTP headers. This shouldn't be a problem, but it's something to keep in mind.
3. Older browsers have smaller limitations on header field sizes than modern browsers, so you need to test across as many as you can get hold of.

Is there are reason you can't use the standard HTTP error codes? I understand that you might want to provide stack traces or other useful debugging information, but in the case of an error, wouldn't you just return a JSON blob that contains the error information, rather than the normal "result" JSON data? You could easily detect the difference based on the HTTP error code and handle the two cases differently.

The reason I'm concerned by your suggested approach is that headers are used to alter or cause browser *behaviour* - they're not intended to be a data storage mechanism.

Pseudo-code example:

```
switch(httpResponseCode)
{
    case 200:
        parseResult(json);
        break;
    case 403:
        parseForbidden(json);
        break;
    case 500:
        parseServerError(json);
        break;
    default:
        // bad response code, handle appropriately
}
```

Comment: The thing with headers is that, as opposed to a JSON reply, they can be set anywhere from the application, which makes it ideal to replace for instance throw exception statements across the application when the call is made through AJAX. Otherwise, if a class that depends on another class which depends on another class fails, the JSON reply data has to be sent back and forth in order to get the error response back, so the choice of the headers seemed natural to save time. But maybe I'm just being lazy.

Comment: Great points either way. Somehow it already felt natural to prefix the header with the application name.

Comment: Why not just have a global array variable to store such headers? You can serialize the array down into JSON when you write the result back to the client.